# Closing Lotus notes via access 2010 vba

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, lotus

I am able to open lotus notes via access 2010 vba.  I can attach an excel spreadsheet.

I cannot find anything on how to shut down Lotus notes once I am done sending my message.

I have tried appactivate "Lotus Notes" and send keys of alt f4 but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without any code... Try to set your Lotus Notes object to "nothing" after your process.

```
Set objLotusNotes = Nothing
```

Comment: Dim Maildb As Object     Dim UserName As String 
    Dim MailDbName As String
    Dim MailDoc As Object     Dim stSignature As String
    Dim attachme As Object     Dim Session As Object     Dim EmbedObj As Object     Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    UserName = Session.UserName
    MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
    Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
     If Maildb.ISOPEN = True Then
     Else
         Maildb.OPENMAIL
     End If

Comment: Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
        MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM ("Attachment")
    MailDoc.PostedDate = Now() 
    MailDoc.Send 0, Recipient
    Maildb.Close
    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set attachme = Nothing
    Set EmbedObj = Nothing
    Session.Close
    Set Session = Nothing

Comment: You're using Notes.NotesSession, which is OLE class, maybe that's the problem. Do you really need to open LotusNotes? Maybe try using "Lotus Domino Objects", which is COM class (Win32 only). If not, try to use windows API call to find Lotus Notes Window and then close it : Win32 API - FindWindow and SendMessage

Comment: I implemented the sendmessage on friday.  Thanks for  your help.  I would like to see the example via lotus domino objects